# Angular how to toggle between search and results view and pass data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services

So I am trying to do the following which I am sure is very common but haven't come across this example.

**View 1 and Controller 1 :**

Have a simple view with a textbox with ng-model="searchTerm" and ngSubmit event. Webservice gets hit with the search term and want to show results on next screen.

**View 2 and Controller 2**

When the user hits submit the view changes to results screen, where the results from the webservice are displayed.

1) What would be the normal way of changing the screen visually like this, using routing and changing views ? Or using ng-show/ng-hide ?

2) How do I pass the search term from controller 1 to controller 2 ?

Comment: If you do it using routing, you have the advantage of having a URL for the results that the user can bookmark, go back to, share, copy, etc. If you use routing, you would use the `$routeParams` to get access to the search query from the route params object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be something like this (I haven't tested this):

#### View 1 and Controller 1:

View:

```
<form ng-submit="showResults(searchTerm)">
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchTerm">
</form>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.showResults = function (searchTerm) {
     // just redirect, the second page will take care of making the query
     // make sure to inject $location into your controller
     $location.url('/results?q=' + encodeURIComponent(searchTerm));
});
```

#### View 2 and Controller 2:

I'm assuming this view is defined for the route `/results`.

Controller:

```
app.controller('SearchResultsCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', function ($scope, $location, $http) {
    // watch the query string parameter for changes, so you can update it 
    // and have the query re-run.
    $scope.$watch(function () {
        return ($location.search() || {}).q;
    }, function (searchTerm) {
        // make webservice call using $http or whatever, e.g.
        $http.get('/api/search?q=' + searchTerm).then(function (data) {
            $scope.results = data;
        });
    });
 }]);
```

Then just work with the `results` scope property however you like in your view.

Answer (score 0):

1.Routing will cause your page to change and it will involve a client-server interaction. This may cause an overhead if you have constraint on the bandwidth. ng-show and ng-hide will just toggle the display of a page which is already existing there, basically it will be a single page. So you need to choose depending on the requirement.

2.The answer depends on what exactly you want your application to do. Does your application need to store the search strings which you have hit? if it does we can go for storing them in a service. However this will not store your values across sessions.

Also we can append it in URL as GregL as said in the comments, that wont store the string in case of multiple search hits. Say you want to know what you searched before doing any search, in that case appending it to routeParams and other URL params will become to clumsy to handle. In that case i would suggest you to use a service. But storage and previous values are of no importance to you, you can do it simply by using routeParam.

Answer (score 0):

The most common and correct approach to work with search functionality, is that the search query is reflected by corresponding GET parameter in URL. It is so in old school websites, and in single page applications as well. The idea is that the results screen must correspond to the current search term and of course be bookmarkable.

For this you can make use of `ngRoute` module which allows you to set up simple routing system.

Below is some basic example:

```
// Configure routes
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/home', {
        controller: 'HomeController',
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
    .when('/search-results', {
        controller: 'SearchResultsController',
        templateUrl: 'results.html'
    })
    .otherwise('/home');
});

// This controller will handle form submission and redirect to search controller
app.controller('HomeController', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.search = function() {
        $location.path('/search-results').search({query: $scope.query});
    };
});

// This controller takes search query from the URL and uses it to make search request
app.controller('SearchResultsController', function($scope, $routeParams, $location) {
    $scope.query = $routeParams.query;
    $scope.url   = $location.absUrl();

    // load search result with some GET request using $scope.query term
});
```

#### Simple Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/FMRTTbxdNv0pGSYpfwve?p=preview